# JavaScript, reduce. Need function that makes array to object

Tags: javascript, reduce

Reduce method is not easy, help me with this problem pls.

i need a function, that receive array with anything, and returns object with fields

```
{field1, field2, field3, field4}
```

like in the example:
Input:

```
[true,6,'wow','you are smart, bro']
```

Output:

```
{field1: true, field2:1, field3: 'wow', field4: 'you are smart, bro'}
```

Comment: can you line out what you've tried already ?

Answer (score 7):

A solution that uses [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/fromEntries) (browsers that support ECMAScript 2019 only):

```js
const arr = [true, 6, 'wow', 'you are smart, bro'];

const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((x, i) => [`field${i + 1}`, x]));

console.log(result);
```

A solution that uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) and ECMAScript 2015:

```js
const arr = [true, 6, 'wow', 'you are smart, bro'];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => ({ ...acc, [(`field${i + 1}`)]: cur }), {});

console.log(result);
```

And a solution that uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) and ECMAScript 5 (browsers as old as IE11):

```js
var arr = [true, 6, 'wow', 'you are smart, bro'];

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
    acc['field' + (i + 1)] = cur;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Solution

```js
const arr = [true,1,'wow','you are smart, bro']

const f = (acc, rec, index) => {
  acc[`field${index + 1}`] = rec //
  return acc
}

const result = arr.reduce(f, {})
console.log(result)
```

#### Explanation

I extracted the callback function into `f` variable for readability's sake.

The callback function expects the following input: accumulator `acc` to store the results in, the value of the current processed element `rec`, and `index`.

```
const f = (acc, rec, index) => {...}
```

The `index` is optional but we need to get array indexes anyway to use them in our resulting object's keys. We know that array's index count starts from `0` and not from `1`, so we have to add `+ 1` to the count to get `field1` key instead of `field0`.

I chose to use string interpolation to get the necessary result:

```
`field${index + 1}`
```

Then we assign the corresponding array element to the object under the key we've just constructed:

```
acc[`field${index + 1}`] = rec
```

The reduce function expects the following input: callback (function `f` ) and initial value, which here should be an empty object `{}`, since we need to have an object as result.

```
reduce(f, {})
```

Now we create new variable `result` which will be the output of the reduce function on each element of the array `arr`:

```
const result = arr.reduce(f, {})
```

Comment: Its always great to have an answer but including an explanation of how you fixed it is amazing!

Comment: Thanks for the tip @mw509 I've just updated my answer and added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [true,6,'wow','you are smart, bro'] 
const obj  = arr.reduce(
  (acc, rec, index) => ({ ...acc, [`field${index + 1}`]: rec }),
  {}
)

console.log(obj)
```

You need always remember that index start from 0

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = [true,6,'wow','you are smart, bro']
.reduce((acc, rec, i) => ({...acc, [`field${i + 1}`]: rec}),{})


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const database = [true, 1, "wow", "you are smart, bro"];

const result = (arr) => arr.reduce(
  (acc, rec, i) => ({
    ...acc, 
    [`field${i + 1}`]: rec
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(result(database));
```

1 step:

```
acc(0 elements) + field{0+1}: true
     |
 accumulator is empty
```

2 step:

```
acc(1 element) + field{1+1}: 1
     |
 field1: true
```

3 step:

```
acc(2 elements) + field{2+1}: "wow"
     |
 field1: true
 field2: 1
```

4 step:

```
acc(3 elements) + field{3+1}: "you are smart, bro"
     |
 field1: true
 field2: 1
 field3: "wow"
```

end:

```
 field1: true
 field2: 1
 field3: "wow"
 field4: "you are smart, bro"
```